# Как присвоить по ссылке созданный объект на лету

Tags: php, ооп

Есть следующий код:

```
class A
{
    public $value = 100;
}
$property = &(new A)->value; /// Это не работает
```

Как быть? Отдельно писать строки типа этого:

```
$obj = new A;
$property = &obj->value;
```

не предлагать!

P.S Ожидаю ответ в стиле: **Никак**

Comment: Собственно, а что вы пытаетесь добиться таким способом `$property = &(new A)->value`?  ссылаться можно на поле созданного экземпляра....ну либо статик..... логично, что без создания экземпляра и последующего ссылания на него  как-то бессмысленно всё

Comment: Но ведь существуют записи аля: `$property = &$obj_of_A->value;` и все нормально работает, помимо этого можно не использовать присвоение по ссылке то есть `$property = (new A)->value;` и то же будет прекрасно работать, ваш комментарий по этому поводу мне непонятен!

Comment: что именно будет нормально работать при `$property = (new A)->value`? вы копируете значение поля объекта и все. далее тот объект помрет на ближайших строках, уберется GC и вы будете работать с копией значения того самого поля класса. никаких ссылок там не будет...........`$property = &$obj_of_A->value;`  работает потому, что уже был создан экземпляр класса и он будет жить долго и счастливо ссылаясь на адрес в памяти пока вы его не убьете.... поэтому тут происходит уже присвоение по ссылке.......ибо есть чем манипулировать..

Comment: `$property = &(new A)->value;` тут вы пытаетесь взять ссылку на поле объекта, который даже не был создан. грубо говоря никаких адресов не было выделено а вы хотите на него сослаться..... сослаться в бездну......даже не могу представить куда так можно сослаться)) Как я уже писал: вариант когда поле будет существовать, если оно статичное, т.е. не привязано к объекту

Comment: окей я вас понял!